# MVVM shared state with animated views

Tags: android, mvvm, fragment, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Assuming I have 2 fragments A and B. Each of them contains a view respectively viewA and viewB. Both views are hidden by default.

There is a shared view model called sharedVM (linked to the activity)

An event A from the user will show viewA with animation and hide viewB with animation (if viewB is visible)
An event B from the user will show viewB with animation and hide viewA with animation (if viewA is visible)

I though about:

**Solution 1:**
Use a LiveData state inside sharedVM to know if views are hidden or visible.
But then when the fragment is destroyed and recreated:
The **hide/show animation will play again**, that's not good.

**Solution 2:**
Use LiveDataEvent inside sharedVM to know dispatch and trigger the animations.
But then when the fragment is destroyed and recreated:
**I have no idea about the previous states of the views**...

What would be a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need:

1. manually restore view state (according current state in `LiveData`) when fragment recreated
2. make view state observer ignore change if view currently in this state

You can do it in `onViewCreated()` callback. This fix make your first solution works.